# Is64BitWindows From Silverlight OOB?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

How to check if the `Windows` machine is `32bit` or `64bit` from `Silverlight OOB`.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I don't believe the answer below tells the architecture, it just means that you have windows version NT or greater

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work

```
if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
{
   if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
   {}
}
```